# Admission for MS/Phd in Computer Science after BE/BTech from India

Tags: phd, thesis, masters, computer-science, india

Should I go for MS/Phd CS (Masters en route to Phd) in USA? I'm very Passionate about research in my field. But I have very little to no research experience. But have done internship in my field of area. But I'm average in my academics. rest of the requirement I can satisfy like SOPs and Recommendation letter. also my Gre score is 324. should I apply?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't apply, you don't get accepted. But you know that already.

I don't know how to evaluate your undergraduate education, nor should you ask this site for an evaluation. But it will be evaluated by any school you apply to. The analysis (breakdown) of your GRE will also depend on the field you are in, in this case CS. Lack of research may not be an issue for an entering MS student, but that depends, like everything on the institution.

Being just "average" in your academics doesn't sound like a plus. However if the entire institution is very rigorous, then that needs to be taken into consideration. Being average among the world's ten best scholars is not so bad.

Your acceptance, however, will depend on more than numbers. The competition for admission is steep so be able to explain in any application what is unique in your background that makes your future success likely.

You can do a quick evaluation of your own, by comparing your own course of study with what you find typically in undergraduate CS programs in the US. If the courses are about the same and you did well you will likely get consideration. But if the courses are vastly different, you will, again, have to show how and why you are qualified. Make your own case.